# Docker can't start - (No such file or directory)

Tags: docker, spring-boot, kotlin, dockerfile

I want to deploy my Spring boot application with docker,  at the moment it is running on AWS Beanstalk without problems.

I have no problems building the container, but when i try to run it like this:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 bogsbinny/mobile-bff
```

then I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundException: ./resources/serviceAccount.json (No such file or directory)
```

I had the same error when I first went from running my Spring app on localhost, to running it on AWS, but it was fixed by marking the resources folder as root resource holder.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
ADD mobile-bff-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

Comment: Can you run the jar on your development machine? Have you checked that ./resources/serviceAccount.json is inside your jar (assuming it is loaded via Class Path)

Comment: It runs on my dev machines yes.

Comment: If i use the terminal to new the jar file, then i see this:
BOOT-INF/classes/serviceAccount.json

Comment: Docker does not change your jar file, it seems odd that it is working locally but not inside the container. Note that inside your jar, the file is not in `resources` but inside `classes`. (probably copied by your build process